# How to view LuraWave images on Linux?

Tags: linux, images, file-format, pictures

I have a number of images I compressed as LuraWave before I knew about advantages of open formats in general and Jpeg2000 or c44 in particular.

What is the simplest way to view *.lwf images in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://www.file-extensions.org/xnview-file-extensions), [XnView](http://www.xnview.com) can do it. Have you tried GIMP? I've yet to find a format GIMP can't deal with (you probably just did though).

Comment: Yes, gimp-2.7 can't open it. `file` returns `\0 "WV\002"` instead of the file type.

Comment: @Vi. Did you try Xnview? It looks promising.

Comment: Not yet downloaded. When I try I'll comment here.

Comment: `/mnt/...../Sonata.lwf 0x0x0 : not a picture` - xnconvert installed from Debian package fails to read it. Maybe it needs some plugins?

Comment: Yes, [this](http://www.xnview.com/en/formats.html) page mentions for lwf `Plugin required, Windows only`.